# Is it possible to use stored procedure like complex querying in Jboss Data Grid?

Tags: datagrid, infinispan, querying, in-memory

We have a web service which calls the stored procedure to get the data which will be sent back to the UI application. The stored procedure sometime takes long time to complete, so we are planning to load the data from database to datagrid and execute data grid query to get the data. Is it possible to run complex query in datagrid (stored procedure has multiple union and conditions in where clause). Reading the documentation I could see only basic querying can be done on Data Grid.

Comment: Are you using library mode or client server mode?

Comment: Client Server mode